# macOS Monterey – Control Centre memory leak

Tags: macos, notifications, monterey, memory-leak

is there any solution for the macOS Monterey memory leak? At least since 12.2 the Notification Center process consumes memory and more memory over time, requiring even ≥4 GBs after a few hours of running. Killing the process temporally helps, however, the issue occurs again after some time.

Comment: Are you on 12.3? Most reports are from early versions of the OS. (It's less than 100Mb on my Intel and M1 Macs running 12.3.)

Comment: Yes. macOS 12.3.1.

Comment: consider restarting your mac. If issue persists after a restart, the issue might be caused by a copprupted system component and a reinstall of macOS might be needed.

Comment: Let's look at where the memory allocations are going. Can you save the output of `vmmap NotificationCenter` to a text file, upload it to a place like www.PasteBin.com, and add the link to the file in your original question?

Comment: I am sorry for the delay. Here's the log as GitHub gist (too long for pastebin): https://gist.github.com/meme1255/7b88f791e4f0619716a155ceba70f888